# Favorite group that was created by MS Teams cannot be set as favorite

Tags: c#, office365, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to add and remove favorites of groups.
Therefore MS Graph provides the `groups/{groupId}/addFavorite` Endpoint to set a group as favorite. When I create a group e.g. by Outlook to favorite this group is possible. When I create a group over MS Teams the endpoint returns me an OK but the groups is not set as favorite. Why does it not work?

I figured out that in via MS Teams created groups, the outlook and calendar icon is hidden. However, it is possible go to outlook for this group by enter the link by hand in the browser. There it is not possible to set the group as favorite over the setting too [See below image *Group created via MS Teams*].

For a group created by Outlook it is possible to favorite it [See below image *Group created via Outlook*].

**Group created via Outlook**

[image: Via Outlook created Group]

**Group created via MS Teams**

[image: Via Teams created Group]

This behavior is the same as in the MS graph endpoint. So when I try to set a via teams created group as favorite via `groups/{groupId}/addFavorite` the endpoint return ok but nothing happens.
I expect, that it should not matter, where I create the group to use the favorite endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that when you create a group via MS Teams the UnifiedGroup property `HiddenFromExchangeClientsEnabled` is `true`. So Outlook and Calendar is not shown and it is not possible to get the isFavorite property. Now I set the `HiddenFromExchangeClientsEnabled` property to false and now it is possible to set it as favorite. :-)

Use `set-UnifiedGroup -identity "TEAMNAME" -HiddenFromExchangeClientsEnabled:$false -Verbose` to set the property.

The next challenge will be to set this property on creation for each new group via ms team.

Comment: Use following comand in Powershell to set the property:
1. `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`
2. `$UserCredential = Get-Credential`
3. `$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection`
4. `Import-PSSession $Session
set-UnifiedGroup -identity "TeamNameHere" -HiddenFromExchangeClientsEnabled:$false -Verbose`

[link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Teams/New-Team-is-not-showing-up-in-Outlook-Desktop/td-p/214314)